# htaccess which allows both http and https - change to allow/redirect to https only

Tags: .htaccess

I have inherited the following htaccess, and am having issues getting it to always redirect to https.

Currently it allows for both http://www and https://www, but I'm wanting it to always redirect to https://www (subdomains should always redirect to https://subdomain.example.com)

All my attempts so far have caused 500 errors, so I'm obviously missing something.

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

RewriteEngine On

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !sub/
RewriteRule (.*) /sub/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can tweak your rules as:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# handle sub-domains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)[^.]+\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# handle main domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)[^.]+\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) sub/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks! That's almost it, except it rewrites subdomains as `www.sub.example.com` where it should just be `sub.example.com`

It should only rewrite `example.com` as `www.example.com`